# add subdomain if namespace present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Not sure if my topic title is correct, but here is my question

I have namespace called `:admin`, so it looks like `mysite.com/admin`. In this section i have some links, that pointing to controllers inside this namespace. But since we have subdomain admin, and my namespace `:admin` as well, i'd like to all links that are being generated by `routes.rb` to prepend string `admin.`, so the link would look like `admin.mysite.com/admin/some_other_path`

I've tried to add constraints to `routes.rb`, but that didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But since we have subdomain admin, and my namespace :admin as well,
>   i'd like to all links that are being generated by routes.rb to prepend
>   string admin.

---

**Routes**

In your routes, you should have this:

```
constraints({ subdomain: "admin" }) do
    namespace :admin do
        # routes here
    end
end
```

If you wanted to have no path for your admin namespace (I.E `admin.domain.com/some_other_path`), you can do this:

```
constraints({ subdomain: "admin" }) do
    namespace :admin, path: "" do
        # routes here
    end
end
```

--

**URL**

When using URLs, you have to use the `_url` helpers (not `_path`). We literally just discovered this yesterday - the `_path` helpers only work to append relative paths to your url; the `_url` gives you a totally fresh url

This means if you have a route as follows:

```
admin_root_path "admin/application#index, constraints => {subdomain: "admin"}
```

You'll call this with this route helper:

```
<%= link_to "Admin", admin_root_url %>
```

This will prepend the required subdomain for you when calling links etc

Answer (score 0):

Define routes in `routes.rb` under admin namespace like this

```
namespace :admin, path: '/', constraints: { subdomain: 'admin' } do
  constraints(Subdomain) do
    # your routes
  end
end
```

Routes defined under this block will always come under admin in link, e.g., `/admin/some_other_path`

To add subdomain to the admin namespace take a look at this question

[Rails namespace admin on custom subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319463/rails-namespace-admin-on-custom-subdomain)

Comment: thats what i have at the moment. But i want all links under this namepspace to have subdomain `admin`

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
  namespace :admin do
    # ...
  end
end
```